# prevent pi from turning tv on

Tags: hdmi

I have a Pi (with Raspbmc installed on it) connected to an LG TV. I disabled the CEC options in XBMC related to turning the TV on/off. However, the Pi keeps turning the TV on when rebooting. I can confirm it's the Pi and not XBMC as the TV comes on before XBMC loads. Is there any way to prevent Pi from turning the TV on? I understand that it sends a signal through HDMI when it comes on, but does it send a "wake up" signal? If so, is there any way to prevent it? It's not fun to come back from work or to wake up and see the TV's been on for hours... Thanks!

Comment: If it helps, the functionality causing this is HDMI CEC.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try editing `/boot/config.txt` to include the line

```
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
```

If you're using OpenElec, the file is `/flash/config.txt`

More info on config.txt options can be found on [the elinux wiki pages](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about that option.

Comment: damned for me, this option doesn't change anything with my bravia ...

Comment: I had to mount /boot as rw in order to do, similar to wiki.openelec.tv/index.php/Config.txt#Editing_config.txt

Answer (score 3):

Preferences > System > Input Devices > Peripherals > CEC Adapter Settings
Uncheck the option: "Switch source to this device on startup"

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1. Disable turning TV on on boot and keep CEC adapter active.

1. Put the following line into the `/boot/config.txt`

   ```
   hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
   ```
2. Update the following Kodi settings in the `Settings > System > Input > Peripherals > CEC Adapter`

   ```
   Switch source to this device on startup = off
   Devices to power on during startup = None
   Wake device when deactivating the screensaver = off
   ```
3. Turn TV off manually
4. Reboot Raspberry

**Result:** TV is off after Raspberry reboot

### Solution 2. Disable turning TV on on boot by disabling CEC adapter.

1. Put the following line into the `/boot/config.txt`

   ```
   hdmi_ignore_cec=1
   ```
2. Turn TV off manually
3. Reboot Raspberry

**Result:** TV is off after Raspberry reboot

---

Raspbian 10 (buster)

Kodi 18.5