# Trying to prevent Pi from turning on TV

Tags: kodi, osmc

I'm running OSMC and I'm trying to make it not turn on my LG TV, and *only* prevent that, with no side effects.

So far, the instructions in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/prevent-pi-from-turning-tv-on) work, except that now I can't use CEC to control Kodi. Whenever I disable "Switch source to this device on startup" in Kodi and reboot, I can no longer use CEC.

I don't understand. I was under the impression that it would just not tell the TV to display the HDMI channel the Pi is on. Does this setting do something else?

The order in which the TV/Pi is powered on does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that now I need to go into TV menus and manually select a CEC device to use it — this has never been necessary before and I don't know why it has to be now.

It's weird that the Pi *must* "wake" the TV for things to work automatically.